# Limit common javascript function execution to a element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to limit common javascript function execution to an element. Suppose I have three div elememts:

```
<div id="a"><div class="d"></div></div>
<div id="b"><div class="d"></div></div>
<div id="c"><div class="d"></div></div>
```

And a function like:

```
changeColor function(){ $(".d").callOtherFunction();  });
changeColor();
```

What I want to do, is to limit function execution just for the element `d` of `#a` without changing definition of `changeColor`.

Thanks in advance.

See : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ugup9rw/) when i click on change color link background of every div is changing. I do not want this , I want background of first div should change. 
Please note that i do not want to change the definition of the changeColor Function is fiddle

Comment: what are you trying to say

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the scope of a global javascript function to some element?

Comment: for which id you dont want to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make `changeColor()` be applied just for `#a .d` element, without changing the function, is to remove class `a` from `#b` and `#c` ascenders.

```
$('#b .d, #c .d').removecClass('d');
changeColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly. You wanted to select `class` `d` and excluding `id=a`

```
changeColor function(){ $(".d").not("#a").callOtherFunction();  });
    changeColor();
```

Comment: some thing like this but i want this function to be executed for #a

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/9ugup9rw/ if want when we click on change color link background of #parent1 should change

Comment: Than why dont try direct like this `changeColor function(){ $("#a").callOtherFunction();  });`